# ng build error when adding adding a factory in providers

Tags: angular, http, build, factory, angular-http

I'm working on a project at school. I created a basic HttpFactory and added it to the provider in app.module.ts but when I'm running ng build, I got this error :

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'provide' of undefined

Thanks.

Code from app.module.ts, Http, HttpFactory, XHRBackend and RequestOptions are imported :

```
providers: [
    AppSettings,
    ProductService,
    CommandService,
    BetService,
    AccountService,
    MasterService,
    ProductCategoryService,
    MasterService,
    UserWalletService,
    TransactionService,
    Window,
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: HttpFactory,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.14",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you misspelled `HttpFactory`. It is `httpFactory` with lowercase h. So it can't read undefined property.

```
Window,
{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: httpFactory,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

Comment: I named it HttpFactory and the import worked fine : import { HttpFactory } from "./factories/httpfactory.factory";
:/

Comment: Okz... If you are making your own factory make sure you implements factory interface it will help you rule out the error.
If you attach the factory source code it will be much easy to look what went wrong...

Comment: actually i figured out, it was the 'Window' provider, I was before working on a visual studio project, now that I'm on a project compiled with cli, I had to remove it (I didn't replace it yet). Thanks.